# How to implement a Certificate-based JAAS LoginModule

Tags: portability, x509certificate, jaas, client-certificates

To authenticate a user, a JAAS `LoginModule` ask its environment about the user's data and credentials by passing appropriate `Callback`'s to its enclosing `CallbackHandler`. The same mechanism is also used for user interaction.

If the only information that the `LoginModule` needs to do its authentication are username and password there is no problem: one uses the standard `Callback` types `javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback` and `javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback`. But apparently there is no such standard for retrieving an X509 certificate.

So how does a `LoginModule` asks its environment about X509 certificates? I know that there are application-server-specific `Callback` types for this, but I am looking for a portable solution if there are any.